# How to add new variables into objects to use in classes

Tags: python, class, object

I have the code:

```
import timedelta
class Tune:

    def __init__(self, title, artist, duration):
        self.title = title
        self.artist = artist
        self.duration = duration

class Play:

    def __init__(self):
        self.tracks = []

    def add(self, song):
        self.tracks.append(song)

    def delete(self, number):
       
         del (self.song(number))
    
    def look(self, song):
        for song in self.tracks:
            print(f"{song.artist} - {song.title}")

    def duration(self):
    
        s=0
        for y in range(0,len(self.song)):
           s = s + self.song[y]
        print(int(datetime.timedelta(seconds=s)))


n = int(input("Enter the number of tracks to add"))
playlist = Play()

for i in range(n):
    title, artist, duration = input("Enter the title, artist, and duration of a track").split(',')
    song = Tune(title, artist, duration)
    playlist.add(song)


playlist.look()
playlist.duration
playlist.delete (2)
```

for every input, i have to make it an object pertaining to its class and add it to the list, with the option of removing it when it is called. When song.look is called, it is supposed to print out the title and artist in the list. For example, if the input is:

```
2
Artic Monkeys,R U Mine?,324
Artic Monkeys,Do I wanna know?,253
```

when the program is executed it should output:

```
1 - Artic Monkeys - R U Mine?
2 - Artic Monkeys - Do I wanna know?
```

when duration is executed:

```
00:09:62
```

when the delete is executed:

```
1 - Artic Monkeys - R U Mine?
```

and if song.duration is called, it should output the total duration in the format of hours:minutes:seconds. I think the add and look is correct, my only problem is how do i make it so that it can have track number and how can i use it to remove said tracks? and is my program for duration correct?

Edit: I can only change the def for the class Play, I cant change the contents of Tune

Comment: So, you are facing a problem in which functionality? is it while deleting?

Comment: yes, and the duration. My main problem is that i dont know how to add the variable "number" seeing as Tune is only defined by the title artist and duration. And I dont know if how the duration part is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import time
class Tune:
    def __init__(self, title, artist, duration):
        self.title = title
        self.artist = artist
        self.duration = duration
        
class Play:

    def __init__(self):
        self.tracks = []

    def add(self, song):
        self.tracks.append(song)

    def delete(self, number):
        self.tracks.pop(number-1)

    def look(self):
        for i in range(len(self.tracks)):
            print(f"{i+1} -{self.tracks[i].artist} - {self.tracks[i].title}")

    def duration(self):
        s = 0
        for y in range(len(self.tracks)):
            s += int(self.tracks[y].duration)
        
        print(time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(s)))


n = int(input("Enter the number of tracks to add"))
playlist = Play()

for i in range(n):
    title, artist, duration = input("Enter the title, artist, and duration of a track").split(',')
    song = Tune(title, artist, duration)
    playlist.add(song)


playlist.look()
playlist.duration()
print("After Deleting 2nd....")
playlist.delete (2)
playlist.look()
print("After Deleting 2nd....")
playlist.delete (2)
playlist.look()
```

[image]

Comment: the tesing should be 2 when 2 is deleted, other than that, works great!

Comment: Hi, I just found out that I can't change the contents of the class Tune, so the algorithm you put can't be used

Comment: I have edited the solution, where tune class is as it is, take a look at it.

Comment: the number is used just for display purposes here, instead of storing it anywhere so now in the edited version of code it is not changing the content of Tune class.

Comment: It works! im glad you took the time to explain where the number is, I was wondering where it is, totally makes sense now. Thank you!